# Accessing Spring boot Application refused to connect with IP 192.168.99.100 running in docker tool box

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I am running a spring boot application in docker tool box. The application runs on port 8380 as set in application properties. However, when i run its image in a container, I am publishing with ports 8380:8082. When i access it from ip 192.168.99.100 (my docker machine ip) and port 8380, it gives me **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** error. 192.168.99.100 refused to connect.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

I have tried using localhost instead of docker-machine ip. I checked the access url from kitematic i.e 192.168.99.100:8380. Using this it does not work.

Here is my DockerFile:

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8082
ADD /build/libs/tsi-csrportal-gui-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar dockerDemoCsrportal.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-DTSI_APP_NAME=csrportal", "-DTSI_ENV=test", "-Dtsi.log.console", "-jar", "dockerDemoCsrportal.jar"]
```

I expect the service to give json response when I access with the proper endpoint. Similar to when I run the spring boot application without docker toolbox. (Only change is that now I use docker machine ip instead of using localhost)

Comment: Does your application run on port 8082 ? If not please expose the port that your application runs on in your DockerFile.

Comment: thanks @NareshKumar. my application runs on port 8380. I exposed it in my DockerFile and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you expose a port in docker it means you can access to that container using `[container_ip]:[exposed_port]`.
But when you map the exposed port to another port it means that you can access to the container using `[host_ip]:[mapped_port]`.
So you can access like `localhost:8380` or `192.168.99.100:8082`

Comment: i tried localhost:8380, 192.168.99.100:8082, 192.168.99.100:8380 none of them are working. It still says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.